# A property of the space of rcll functions

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> Let $E$ be a locally compact separable metric space, 
>   $$\Omega=\{f:[0,\infty]\to E\mid f \text{ is rcll}\}$$
>   and $P$ be a probability on $\Omega$ which equiped the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all of the coordinate maps.
>   $$\Lambda_t=\{f\mid f(t-)\neq f(t)\}$$then there are at most countably many $t$ for which $P\{\Lambda_t\}>0$

I think because $f$ is rcll, it has countable discontinuous points. Then each $f$ can only belong to countable sets of $\Lambda_t$. But I don't know how to continue.